# Changing label names in a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to rename the labels within my legend.

My code

```
ggplot(BioPlusMetrics, aes(x = depth, y = temperature, colour = cruise)) +
  labs(x = "Depth", y = "Temperature", colour = "Month") +
  geom_line(size=1, linetype=2)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_hue(direction = -1) +
  scale_x_reverse()+
  scale_y_continuous(position="right")+
  coord_flip()
```

This is the figure that is produced.

[image]

I have tried adding the following line of code

```
 + scale_colour_discrete(labels=c("August","May","November","October")) +
```

But I get this error

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.

Can anyone help me rename my legend labels to

```
"August", "May", "November" and "October"
```

Comment: The problem is that you use both `scale_colour_hue` and `scale_colour_discrete`, that's why you get the error that scale colour is already present. Try deleting the `scale_colour_hue` as you are not specifying a color wheel anyway

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

One way to modify the labels is to change the data before you plot it. Without knowing the structure of your `BioPlusMetrics` data, it is tricky to provide a perfect example.

*If* you have a date column in your data (in date format), then you may extract the name of the month, and put that into a separate column like:

```
BioPlusMetrics <- BioPlusMetrics %>% 
  mutate(
    month_name = format(date, '%B')
  )
```

Basically, `format(date, '%B')` takes your date, and 'reformats' it, into the 'full name of the month' format, specified by `'%B'`. See https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/date-formats-in-r/ for a list of different formats. (Edit: see [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/dates.html) for a list of date *and datetime* formats).

Or an alternative using the `lubridate` package:

```
BioPlusMetrics <- BioPlusMetrics %>%
  mutate(
    month_name = lubridate::month(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
    # label = TRUE means we get the name of the month rather than the number of the month
    # abbr = FALSE means we get the full name, not the 3 letter abbreviation (eg Oct)
  )
```

Once you have this full month name in your data, you could then modify the code for the `ggplot`, using `colour = month_name` instead of `colour = cruise`:

```
# ggplot(BioPlusMetrics, aes(x = depth, y = temperature, colour = cruise)) +
ggplot(BioPlusMetrics, aes(x = depth, y = temperature, colour = month_name)) +
  labs(x = "Depth", y = "Temperature", colour = "Month") +
  geom_line(size=1, linetype=2)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_hue(direction = -1) +
  scale_x_reverse()+
  scale_y_continuous(position="right")+
  coord_flip()
```

Alternatively, you may use `ifelse` to modify the values of `cruise`:

```
BioPlusMetrics <- BioPlusMetrics %>%
  mutate(
    cruise = ifelse(cruise == 'Aug 2013', 'August', cruise),
    # ifelse() above may be read as: "If cruise is 'Aug 2013', change it to 'August', otherwise we keep the existing value in the cruise column"

    cruise = ifelse(cruise == 'May 2014', 'May', cruise),
    # copy and repeat for each value you want to change...
  )
```

If you modify the `cruise` column (instead of making `month_name` in the other examples), you will still specify `colour = cruise` in `ggplot()`.

And as Alex suggested, you probably only need to specify one `scale_colour_*`.